# Getting the length of an array - Prints incorrect value

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have an Array called `arr`. I am adding items to it ( `arr.push(val)` ) and it prints the value as 1 (`arr.length`) - It prints 1 when i add only 1 item.

but, when i add 2 values/items (`arr.push(val)`), i still get the result as `1` and not `2`.

```
var arr=[];
arr.push(val);
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr);
```

When i add **1** value i get the output for `console.log(arr);` as `One`

When i add **2** value i get the output for `console.log(arr);` as `One,Two` (But the Length is printed as 1)

Why is this ? and how can i resolve this.

**UPDATE**

```
checkBox: function (val) {

var arr=[];
arr.push(val.name);
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr);

}
```

Comment: How do you "*add 2 value*"? Post the exact code.

Answer (score 3):

You are re-instantiating your array every time you call that function. Thus it will only have the current value in. You should try:

```
var arr      = [],
    checkbox = function(val) {
        arr.push(val);
        console.log(arr.length);
    };

checkbox('hello');
checkbox('moto');
```

Comment: According to the problem description this is not causing the  issue because he can see both values...

Comment: Just looking at the lower source code section provided, I'm pretty sure that must be happening. In the upper case, you're right, arr only is initialised once.

Ideally a full copy of the code in context would be nice.

Comment: When i add 2 value i get the output for console.log(arr); as One,Two (But the Length is printed as 1) - doesn't sound to me like a reinstantiating error;)

Comment: Yes but the lower source code cannot be what is happening then, because if you try it, arr gets reset to [] each time, so there must be something slightly different going on, and for that we need the source code in the context of how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are pushing a string or an array into that array!

The following works:

```
arr.push("one","two"); // -> arr =["one","two"]
```

this will work too, but put only one element into the array

```
arr.push("one,two"); // -> arr =["one,two"] <- the first element is a string "one,two"
```

this would work in the same way as pushing a string into the array:

```
arr.push(["one","two"]); // arr = [["one","two"]] <- the first element is an array ["one,two"]
```

If it's a string, you need to split it first (e.g. when it's a name) and put the values into the first array using `concat()`

```
var a = [];
var name = "John Doe";
var b = name.split(" "); // creates an array ["John","Doe"]
a.concat(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding two elements to an array should always properly update it's length property, regardless of whether you add them one at a time or in a group.

The only way you could get a discrepency with the length is if you add the two values as an array or a single string, in which case there would only be 1 element in the original array, and that element would be an array containing 2 elements or a single string.

```
var blah = [];
blah.push('foo');
blah.push('bar');
console.log(blah.length); // 2

var boo = [];
boo.push('foo', 'bar');
console.log(boo.length); // 2

var baz = [];
baz.push(['foo', 'bar']);
console.log(baz.length); // 1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EcHtU/